# “Left hemisphere (wing) overview” — 「 左ウィング・上x 」

Tags: kanji

In the video game by Sega named Alien: Isolation, a certain room is named “Left Hemisphere Overview,” and the corresponding Japanese text is 「 左ウィング・上x 」. The x symbol represents a kanji that I am having trouble identifying. Can someone please provide the missing kanji? Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 階{かい} that means floor (storey of a building). Coupled with the kanji 上{うえ} which means "above/up" etc is read 上階{じょうかい} and means "floor above/upstairs".　See all about it [here](http://kakijun.jp/page/1271200.html).

Comment: so then is this a bad translation? left wing -> left hemisphere, upstairs -> overview ?

Comment: Is it impossible to understand 上階 as "above floor," which would seemingly be more related to "overview"? (That is, "above floor" as in "[the view] above floor.")